# How to await for the completion or error of an async download in Dart?

Tags: dart, async-await, download

I'd like to write a multi-stage process linearly (as shown below) that starts with a file download with progress:

```
  /// Processes the database, from download to prices processing.
  Future<void> updateDatabase() async {
    //final fontText = await File('./example/cosmic.flf').readAsString();
    //print(art.renderFiglet('updateDatabase'));

    // == 1) download
    print('1 ======== DOWNLOADING ==========');
    try {
      await startDownloading();
    } catch (err) {}

    // == 2) Decompress: Whatever download was ok or not, we decompress the last downloaded zip file we have locally
    print('2 ======== DECOMPRESSING ========');
    try {
      await startDecompressing();
    } catch (err) {}

    // == i) Stage i, etc.
```

But something does not work in my download stage as it starts stage 2) prior stage 1) completion.

My stage one (download) is like so:

```
  /// Starts download procress
  Future<void> startDownloading() async {
    print("startDownloading…");

    _state = DownloadState.downloading;
    _progress = 0;
    notifyListeners();

    /// Database string url
    final databaseUrlForInstantData = "https://XXX";

    try {
      final request = Request('GET', Uri.parse(databaseUrlForInstantData));

      final StreamedResponse response = await Client().send(request);

      final contentLength = response.contentLength;

      // == Start from zero
      _progress = 0;
      notifyListeners();

      /// The currently downloaded file as an array of bytes
      List<int> bytes = [];

      response.stream.listen(
        /// = Closure listener for newly downloaded bytes
        (List<int> newBytes) {
          bytes.addAll(newBytes);

          final downloadedLength = bytes.length;

          if (contentLength == null) {
            _progress = 0;
          } else {
            _progress = downloadedLength / contentLength;
          }
          notifyListeners();

          print(
              'Download in progress $_progress%: ${bytes.length} bytes so far');
        },

        /// = Download successfully completed
        onDone: () async {
          _state = DownloadState.downloaded;
         
          notifyListeners();

          /// The resulting local copy of the database
          final file = await _getDownloadedZipFile();

          // == Write to file
          await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
          print('Download complete: ${bytes.length} bytes');
        },

        /// = Download error
        onError: (e) {
          _state = DownloadState.error;
          _error = e.message;
          print('Download error at $_progress%: $e');
        },
        cancelOnError: true,
      );
    }
    // == Catches potential error
    catch (e) {
      _state = DownloadState.error;
      _error = 'Could not download the databse: $e';
      print('Download error at $_progress%: $e');
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startDownloading` function returns after it registers callbacks to listen to the `Stream` and does not wait for the `Stream` to complete.

To wait for the `Stream` to complete, you can save the `StreamSubscription` returned by `.listen` and then `await` the `Future` from [`StreamSubscription.asFuture`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/StreamSubscription/asFuture.html):

```dart
var streamSubscription = response.stream.listen(...);
await streamSubscription.asFuture();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I add that once doing like that the onDone and onError are never triggered and you need to write your on done code after the await whilst the on error code must be in the catch section of the try surrounding the await

Comment: I recommend just using `await stream.forEach(...)` instead of using `listen` and the doing gymnastics with the subscription. Or use `await for( ... in stream) { ... }` when possible.